# Programatically report goo.gl shortened URL as spam?

Tags: python, asp.net-web-api, google-url-shortener

I have a list of more than 3500 goo.gl URLs which have been identified as spam.

I need to report them to Google as spamlinks. Google indeed provided a page to report these kinds of spamlinks: https://goo.gl/#reportspam ... unfortunately, it only accepts on and exactly one URL per reporting.

Naturally, 3500+ of URLs means it's no longer sane nor practical to report them manually, one-by-one. Spamlink reporting must be done automatically.

I have been reading [Google's URL Shortener API documentation](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/), and I have also searched the Internet for relevant information, but I can't seem to find any publicly available API for reporting goo.gl linkspams.

Can you direct me to how I can accomplish this automated linkspam reporting?

If possible, with a sample code, preferably using Python.

Comment: You need to explain what "reporting" means in this context to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think the title already made it clear... but for your benefit, I've edited my question to clarify my intent.

Comment: So maybe you will have to report them automatically, one-by-one, maybe?

Comment: @barny yes, but I can't seem to find an API for doing that... and Google's page for reporting goo.gl spamlinks is a model of Javascript Obfuscation --__--

Comment: Maybe use one of those libraries for web scraping that pretends to be a browser, so the js works.

Comment: @barny hmmm, yeah, that might work... let me play around for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: I give up. Too much work to do.

I finally resorted to driving / simulating mouse-clicks and typing using `xdotool` and a `bash` script, running non-stop within a VirtualBox VM (so it can run in the background while I do things in the foreground).

It's not perfect. But it works well enough for my needs. If I left the VM + Script running overnight, it can report over 9'000 spam URLs.

If you're interested in the script, I've uploaded it here:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/pepoluan/78M4X

(too long to paste in StackOverflow)

And this is how everything should be laid out before running the script (note particularly how Firefox is placed flush right and flush top).

[image: How the screen should be laid out before running the script -- This is on Linux Mint 17.3 MATE]

(Note: It's on Linux Mint 17.3 with MATE. On other WMs / distros, you'll need to change the `xpos` and `ypos` values to match the actual layout. Move the mouse so that the pointer hover over the relevant textbox, and use the `xdotool getmouselocation` command.)

(Another **very important note:** DISABLE CLIPBOARD SHARING! You'll save yourself a lot of time wondering why everything go wonky.)

I hope this can be of help to someone!